# Is there a way to get feedback from a process in XUL?

Tags: process, xul

I'm starting to develop an extension which must interact with an external application. I can run the external application as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Running_applications), but I do not see a way to get any feedback. The only information I get is the exit status, while I need to read the application output, as it would appear on a terminal (stdout). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

After running the [nsiProcess](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIProcess#Attributes), loop while checking the isRunning attribute.  When it stops running, check the exitValue attribute. As I understand it, this may behave differently on different platforms, but I did use it successfully on Windows.

Comment: There is no need to loop, I can get an observer notified when the process is finished. But in this I don't find the output, do I? The exit value should be 0 if the process finished correctly and a numeric code different from 0 if there where problems in the execution.

Comment: I don't know about how to get an observer notification, but I do it by having setInterval check the isRunning, and then read exitValue.  Are you saying you are checking the exitValue and it is not being set?

Comment: Sorry, I only read this reply now. I am just saying that the exitValue is not the output. Thank you anyway. To notify an observer, check the method runAsync here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIProcess